# What is the relationship between renderpass, graphics pipeline and draw call in vulkan?

Tags: graphics, rendering, game-development, vulkan

I have a basic knowledge about vulkan and compute graphic. I also have read the vulkan tutorial in https://vulkan-tutorial.com/ . However, I am confused about the relationship between renderpass, graphics pipeline and draw call.

From vulkan API, the graphics pipeline only can hold one renderpass. Does it mean multi-renderpass would need creating multiple graphics pipelines?

Draw call command is recorded in a renderpass, it does not specify any render target, although a renderpass may contain multiple render targets. Does it mean a renderpass only need a draw call? But I often hear something about draw call limits. It seems multiple draw calls likely happen in a renderpass. Why need multiple draw calls?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A graphic pipeline does not "hold" a render pass at all. It is created with respect to a render pass:

> `renderPass` is a handle to a render pass object describing the environment in which the pipeline will be used; the pipeline **must** only be used with an instance of any render pass compatible with the one provided.

Specifically, it is created with respect to a subpass of a render pass (also a field of `VkGraphicsPipelineCreateInfo`). You can only use a graphics pipeline when a render pass instance compatible with `renderPass` is active *and* when the given subpass of that render pass is active.

Subpasses determine which render pass attachments will be rendered to by any rendering operation. So the fragment shader outputs are routed to the active attachments, as specified in the [render pass's subpass data](https://www.khronos.org/registry/vulkan/specs/1.2-khr-extensions/html/chap8.html#VkSubpassDescription) for that subpass.

Draws happen with respect to whatever graphics pipeline is current, and render to the attachments specified by the graphics pipeline's outputs and routed to the attachments for the current subpass of the current render pass instance.